# Error Collecting PyTests After __init__.py Added to src Folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am trying to run PyTest using the Testing extension in VSCode, but it's failing.
My directory structure is as follows:

- `conftest.py` (empty)
- `src`

  - `__init__.py` (has `important_function` that is imported in `main.py`)
  - `main.py`
- `test`

  - `__init__.py` (empty)
  - `test_main.py`

Before I had the `src/__init__.py`, PyTest was able to find the tests without problems.

But now it says:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'important_function' from '__init__' (/Users/ynusinovich/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/__init__.py)`

It seems like VSCode decided to look for the function in its own `__init__` folder, instead of in my `src` folder. Is there any way to direct it to the correct location?

Comment: Could you please paste your `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution:
I renamed the `__init__.py` in the `src` folder to `utils`, and now VSCode's PyTest is no longer confused about where to look for `important_function`.

Comment: I belive the __init__,py does not belong into the src folder. It only belongs into python packages. The src folder should normaly not be a python package!